# how to retrieve string forecolor in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to extract color of string that user has already changed by selecting part of text.
My code uses : document.execCommand("ForeColor", false, "green")
to colorize the selected text.
Thanks,

Comment: You've to get a reference to the parent element of the selected textnode, then you can do `window.getComputedStyle(parent, null).color` to detect the color.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+get+forecolor+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.